# Claims are not mapped and users are not persisted using Federated authentication

Tags: authentication, federated-authentication

I'm using sitecore 9.1. I've implemented an IdentityProvidersProcessor using Microsoft.Owin.Security to authenticate users. I've added my transformations in a config file as below.

```
  <!--list of identity transfromations which are applied to the provider when a user signin-->
      <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
        <!--SetIdpClaim transformation-->
       <transformation name="set idp claim" ref="federatedAuthentication/sharedTransformations/transformation[@name='set idp claim']" />
         <transformation name="Name Identifier Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
            <claim name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" />
          </sources>
          <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
            <claim name="FullName" />
          </targets>
          <keepSource>true</keepSource>
        </transformation>
      </transformations>
    </identityProvider>
  </identityProviders>
```

I have also specified externalUserBuilder node in my config file and specified my custom ExternalUserBuilder class.
I Also added List of property mappings, to map claims into user properties.

When debugging i find the transformations are read as shown in the below screenshots.
However the user custom properties are never read which, i guess, means they were not mapped correctly.

[image]

[image]

When debugging i also find that the sitecore context user is always extranet/anonymous, and the http context user in null! which means that the custom externaluserbuilder is not run successfully.

I'm not sure when is the Custom externalUserBuilder is actually called!

[image]

Any idea what i might be missing here?

Comment: Have you followed this documentation -> https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/configure-federated-authentication.html?

Comment: Take a look also in this blog post series -> https://himadritechblog.wordpress.com/2019/03/14/sitecore-identity-part-3-connecting-to-external-identity-provider/ and github repository -> https://github.com/himadric/IdentityServer4.Samples

Comment: @PeterProcházka yes i followed this documentation. i have a problem that the user is not logged in in both asp.net and sitecore as well.